Доброго времени суток. Помогите в (Inno Setup)
Как в Inno Setup убрать ограничение на установку долее одной программы?? То есть игра установлена нажимаешь на установщик второй раз он игнорирует окно выбора установки и предлагает создать ярлык на работчем столе и просто перезаписывает файлы.

Заголовок вопроса должен содержать его краткую суть

А ещё непонятно в чём проблема, вполне логично ожидать, что один и тот же установщик будет устанавливать одну и ту же программу. Вы зачем-то хотите установить одну и ту же программу несколько раз в разных местах? А зачем? А сама программа вообще поддерживает такой странный режим работы?

Я не встречал инстоляторы  с ограничением на число копий. А программа поддерживает такой режим работы.

Используйте самораспаковывающийся архив вместо инсталлятора.

Связанный вопрос

Добавь скрипт  Inno Setup
